# how to connect jconsole to compiere jboss server using bash script?

Tags: bash, jboss

I am using compiere to connect with jboss AS 4.3. I wrote a script to automate the process of  restarting compiere server and closing store etc. but all i could not able to achieve is to connect with jboss instance shown in jconsole after compiere server restarted. I have to do it manually.  Is there any way i achieve this with the help of script commands..

Answer (score 0):

Which versions? With or without jboss mbeans?

without:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $JAVA_OPTS"
```

with:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-  Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $JAVA_OPTS"
```

Comment: I didnt understand Sirch.. i have updated my question with more brief.. All i am trying is to connect jboss server instance shown in jconsole after i restart the jboss.